# How to get product id and UPC in page source in Target?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape some product ID and UPC of products in Target using Selenium in Python. I cannot find product id and UPC in product page so i go to the page source and find them in there. I try to use selenium and bs4 to get the product id and UPC but it doesn't work. Can anyone explain how to scrape data from web source? Thanks

web source is like this

```
<tr>
   <td class="line-content">
     <span class="html-comment"><!-- --></span>
     "12049604"
```

[image: source]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32new\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.target.com/p/zyrtec-24-hour-allergy-relief-capsules-cetirizine-hcl/-/A-15075282?preselect=12049604#lnk=sametab')
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
a = soup.find("span", {"class":"html-comment"}).get_text()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should like something like this

```
import from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32new\chromedriver_win32 (2)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.target.com/p/zyrtec-24-hour-allergy-relief-capsules-cetirizine-hcl/-/A-15075282?preselect=12049604#lnk=sametab') 

#needed to click onto the "Show more" to get the tcin and upc
timeout = 5
xpath = '//*[@id="tabContent-tab-Details"]/div/button'
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath).click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

#gets a list of all elements under "Specifications"
div = soup.find("div", {"class":"styles__StyledCol-sc-ct8kx6-0 iKGdHS h-padding-h-tight"})
list = div.find_all("div")
for a in range(len(list)):
    list[a] = list[a].text

#locates the elements in the list
tcin = [v for v in list if v.startswith("TCIN")]
upc = [v for v in list if v.startswith("UPC")]

print(tcin)
print(upc)
```

The output will look like this:

```
['TCIN: 12049604']
['UPC: 300450204448']
```

Comment: The code works for a single URL, but when I put 200 URLs, "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached" will occurs when the code run approximately 10 URLs.

Comment: run it in a for loop, if that takes too long look at something like AWS Lambda

Comment: @ Andrew Horowitz. I have solved the problem. Thank you for your help